# FLEX - Custom component Footer-Datagrid - Itemrenderer - "Set data" function not working

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, datagrid, itemrenderer

I'm trying to implement a datagrid with footer as defined with this class :

https://github.com/ncdc/flex-footer-datagrid

It's working perfectly. Nevertheless in a second step I have tried to implement with this package an itemrenderer on one column in order to display the value with a specific style.

Here my code

```
        <footerDataGrid:FooterDataGrid
            id="dg_imActivity" width="100%" 
            dropEnabled="true"
            dragDrop="model.checkIfActivityExixts(event)"
            dataProvider="{grant!=null?model.activities.grantItems:null}" 
            editable="true"
            itemEditEnd="EditBudgetValue(event)"
            rowCount="{grant!=null?dg_imActivity.dataProvider.length + 2:6}"
            >

            <footerDataGrid:columns>
                <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Title" dataField="title" showDataTips="true" dataTipField="title" editable="false"/>
                <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Type" dataField="type" showDataTips="true" dataTipField="type" editable="false"/>
                <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Pr. Area" dataField="prioAreaName" showDataTips="true" dataTipField="prioAreaName" editable="false"/>
                <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Unit" dataField="unitName" showDataTips="true" dataTipField="unitName" editable="false">
                        <mx:itemRenderer>
                            <fx:Component>                                  
                                <mx:HBox paddingLeft="2" horizontalScrollPolicy="off">
                                    <fx:Script>
                                        <![CDATA[
                                            import mx.controls.Alert;
                                            import mx.states.SetStyle;

                                            override public function set data( value:Object ) : void {
                                                super.data = value;

                                                if( data.unitName != outerDocument.user.profile.organ.name ) {
                                                    setStyle("color",0xFF0000);
                                                    setStyle("fontWeight", "bold");
                                                }else{
                                                    setStyle("color",0xffffff);
                                                    setStyle("fontWeight", "normal");
                                                }

                                            }
                                        ]]>
                                    </fx:Script>
                                    <mx:Label text="{data.unitName}" width="100%"/>
                                </mx:HBox>
                            </fx:Component>
                        </mx:itemRenderer>


                </mx:DataGridColumn>
                <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Value" dataField="budgetValue" id="budgetValue" showDataTips="true" dataTipField="budgetValue" editable="true"/>
            </footerDataGrid:columns> 

            <footerDataGrid:footer>
                <footerDataGrid:SummaryFooter>
                    <footerDataGrid:columns>
                        <footerDataGrid:SummaryColumn  label='Total'/>
                        <footerDataGrid:SummaryColumn />
                        <footerDataGrid:SummaryColumn />
                        <footerDataGrid:SummaryColumn />                                                        
                        <footerDataGrid:SummaryColumn operation='sum' precision='2'/>
                    </footerDataGrid:columns>
                </footerDataGrid:SummaryFooter>


                <footerDataGrid:SummaryFooter>
                    <footerDataGrid:columns>
                        <footerDataGrid:SummaryColumn label='Remaining Budget'/>
                        <footerDataGrid:SummaryColumn />
                        <footerDataGrid:SummaryColumn />
                        <footerDataGrid:SummaryColumn />                                                            
                        <footerDataGrid:SummaryColumn labelFunction='remainingBudgetActivity' dataColumn='{budgetValue}'/>
                    </footerDataGrid:columns>
                </footerDataGrid:SummaryFooter>

            </footerDataGrid:footer>
        </footerDataGrid:FooterDataGrid>
```

I obtain an error with the itemrenderer.

```
ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property unitName not found on mx.controls.dataGridClasses.DataGridColumn and there is no default value.
```

The abel is displayed without the style. All is correctly defined. Apparently the method set data() is correctly called, but it cannot retrieve the data object and I do not know the reason. Besides I have tried with a default datagrid and it's working.

Could you please tell me how to solve this problem? I need to use this package because I need to display footer in the datagrid.

Answer (score 0):

I do not why but with this package I have to add a test in order to see if the object property exists:

```
if( "unitName" in data){
    if( data.unitName != outerDocument.user.profile.organ.name ) {
        setStyle("color",0xFF0000);
        setStyle("fontWeight", "bold");
    }else{
        setStyle("color",0x000000);
        setStyle("fontWeight", "normal");
    }
}
```

And now all is working. It was strange because with the default datagrid, no test was necessary.